# Is there any option in Azure Data factory to retain same date format while copying data from source systems

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am copying data from Oracle Table to Azure Data Lake using Azure data factory copy activity.

Where ever my date format is `DD-MM-YYYY`, azure converting them into DATE_TIME format. 
Is there any way to retain the same format as the source

I am able to hard code the format for a specific column if copy activity is for a single table.
In my scenario, I am trying to copy for multiple tables using the same copy activity, so It is not possible to update the schema

Comment: did you tried to copy it like a string?

Comment: @Kiril1512 It worked when we tried with String

Comment: Nice. Now when you have it as string is easier to do what you want to the dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no support for `DATE` as a data type while on ADLS (data lake store). The only supported data type is `DateTime and DateTimeOffset`

In order for you to continue working with the `DATE` data type, the ETL which gets created on top of this data should address this i.e. typecast in the ETL build phase.